# Magento - Extending the shopping cart with extra steps or questions

Tags: magento

Is there such thing as "shopping cart attributes" to allow shopping cart customization?

Basically I need the customer to answer one question before posting his order, something like:

**In case one or more items in your order are not available, what you want us to do?**

1. Please select an answer
2. Send you a similar color or model.
3. Contact you to discuss more options.
4. Cancel "ONLY" the missing item only and refund your credit card.
5. Cancel the whole order and refund your credit card.

This could be a dropdown or some radio buttons.
The idea was to use some build in functionality or extension considering my php sills are not that good.

Thanks in advance;

Answer (score -1):

i think that a good idea is using magento poll.